# Machine learning studio is being recreated when running terraform apply

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-machine-learning-service

I am using Terraform to create azure machine learning studio with compute instances and compute cluster. However, after a while the studio included also models and endpoints. My question is when I run terraform apply again, it destroys the ML studio and create it again.Is there a way to prevent the destruction and recreation of the machine learning studio?

I searched for locking the deletion of machine learning studio but did not find a solution in terraform

Comment: You are probably not saving the state anywhere but it's impossible to tell without you providing any reproducible blocks of code.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I am saving the plan in azure and import the state file in the code

Answer (score 1):

> My question is when I run terraform apply again, it destroys the ML studio and create it again. Is there a way to prevent the destruction and recreation of the machine learning studio?

To prevent recreating the entire `ML workspace` and only update the  values , you can use the  `Terraform lifecycle`  configuration block to manage the behaviour of the resource during updates.

Here is the sample code to update the `ML Workspace` with same code without destroying existing `ML workspace`.

I have added tags to the resources in the same code and ran `Terraform apply` again. It is modifying the values without recreating the `ML Workspace`.

```
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
    
    resource "azurerm_resource_group" "mlrg" {
      name     = "mltg-resources"
      location = "West Europe"
        tags = {
        Environment = "Production"
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_application_insights" "applicationins" {
      name                = "workspace-example-ai"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.mlrg.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.mlrg.name
      application_type    = "web"
        tags = {
        Environment = "Production"
      }
    }
    resource "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
      name                = "venkat-test-vault"
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.mlrg.location
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.mlrg.name
      tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
      sku_name            = "premium"
        tags = {
        Environment = "Production"
      }
    }
    
      resource "azurerm_storage_account" "storageaccount" {
      name                     = "samplestoragefhfjfjfjffj"
      location                 = azurerm_resource_group.mlrg.location
      resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.mlrg.name
      account_tier             = "Standard"
      account_replication_type = "GRS"
        tags = {
        Environment = "Production"
      }
    }
    resource "azurerm_machine_learning_workspace" "alworkspace" {
      name                    = "ml-workspace"
      location                = azurerm_resource_group.mlrg.location
      resource_group_name     = azurerm_resource_group.mlrg.name
      application_insights_id = azurerm_application_insights.applicationins.id
      key_vault_id            = azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
      storage_account_id      = azurerm_storage_account.storageaccount.id
    
      identity {
        type = "SystemAssigned"
      }
      tags = {
        Environment = "Production"
      }
        lifecycle {
        prevent_destroy = true
      }
    }
```

**Terraform apply**

[image]

When I checked the same resource **(ML Workspace)** in the portal, it only updated the tags without destroying the existing values.

[image]

Refer the [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76436762/when-using-terraform-to-increase-the-number-of-max-pods-in-the-default-node-pool/76440064#76440064) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have a question so I am creating the infrastructure in 2 subscriptions development and production. In the development subscription I create the infrastructure for testing and destroy it after that so if I added the life cycle block , I  will get an error „ Resource has lifecycle.prevent_destroy set, but the
│ plan calls for this resource to be destroyed.“ Is there any work around to avoid this?

Comment: The prevent_destroy attribute of the lifecycle block is set based on the value of the workspace variable. If the workspace is set to "development," it will prevent the destruction of the ML workspace. For any other workspace, the prevent_destroy attribute will be set to false, allowing the resource to be destroyed.
lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = development == "development" ? true : false
  }