# Terraform destroying resource on every apply

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, azure-virtual-network, terraform-modules

I am using the below tf template module to create Mongo DB Atlas private link and connect to the Azure private end point .
Pls note I am using a diff module for creating the Mongo Atlas cluster

My problem is every time I do a terraform apply, the Mongo DB Atlas private link is getting destroyed and a new private link is getting created. Is there a way to resolve this . Thanks.

```
resource "mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint" "test" {
  project_id    = var.project_id
  provider_name = "AZURE"
  region        = "eastus2"
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "test" {
  name                = "endpoint-test"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  subnet_id           = azurerm_subnet.test.id
  private_service_connection {
    name                           = mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint.test.private_link_service_name
    private_connection_resource_id = mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint.test.private_link_service_resource_id
    is_manual_connection           = true
    request_message                = "Azure Private Link test"
  }

}

resource "mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint_service" "test" {
  project_id                  = mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint.test.project_id
  private_link_id             = mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint.test.private_link_id
  endpoint_service_id         = azurerm_private_endpoint.test.id
  private_endpoint_ip_address = azurerm_private_endpoint.test.private_service_connection.0.private_ip_address
  provider_name               = "AZURE"
}
```

Comment: Please add the plan output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My problem is every time I do a terraform apply, the Mongo DB Atlasprivate link is getting destroyed and a new private link is getting created. Is there a way to resolve this

The `mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint` resource is still being recreated on every `terraform apply`, even without any changes. This could be due to changes in the state of the resources or the way `Terraform` detects changes.

You can verify the `Terraform state` to see if there are any changes detected in the `mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint` resource before running `terraform apply` using below commands.

```
terraform state list 
terraform state show mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint.test
```

As I don't have a subscription to create a `MongoDB Atlas` cluster for testing, I've used a storage account to check the `terraform state show` command.

[image]

Alternatively, you can also use the `Terraform lifecycle` configuration block to prevent the recreation of the `mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint` on every `terraform apply`.

```json
resource "mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint_service" "test" {
  project_id                  = mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint.test.project_id
  private_link_id             = mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint.test.private_link_id
  endpoint_service_id         = azurerm_private_endpoint.test.id
  private_endpoint_ip_address = azurerm_private_endpoint.test.private_service_connection.0.private_ip_address
  provider_name               = "AZURE"
lifecycle {
    prevent_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Refer the [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76436762/when-using-terraform-to-increase-the-number-of-max-pods-in-the-default-node-pool/76440064#76440064) related to same issue answered by Me

Comment: Thanks yes the lifecycle configuration worked good. Thanks.

```lifecycle {
   ignore_changes = [private_link_id]
}```